# Proper way to set up and document unlimited-parameters to function?

Tags: php, phpdoc, function-declaration

**Background:**
I am creating a method `addAll` that adds all of the values passed to the method to my class.  Here's what I was thinking:

```
public function addAll() {
    if(func_num_args()===0) {
        throw new BadMethodCallException(get_class($this).'::addAll() must have arguments.');
    }

    $args = func_get_args();

    foreach($args as &$arg) {
        $this->add($arg);
    }
}
```

And it works great.  Then I got to documenting it with phpDocumentor:

```
/**
 * @param mixed ... All of the values to add.
 */
```

. . . but I don't have a name for my `@param` because, frankly, it doesn't exist.

**Question: How do I construct and define something like this?**

---

Since I want it to have at least one value passed in, I came up with this but am unsure:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $value,... All of the values to add.
 */
public function addAll($value) {
    $args = func_get_args();

    foreach($args as &$arg) {
        $this->add($arg);
    }
}
```

It seems so wrong because `$value` is never directly used. . .

Also, I already have `add` which adds one, so shouldn't `addAll` semantically require at least two parameters?  What would you recommend for defining and documenting that?

Comment: I would use your second example and additionally comment the class properties at the beginning of the class, but I also think, this has a lot to do with coding conventions. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871204/how-to-document-an-accessor-mutator-method-in-phpdoc-javadoc

Comment: The second example fits the demonstrated usage for handling "unlimited arguments" as shown in the phpDocumentor manual -- http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html

Comment: @ashnazg I ended up restructing my code altogether to avoid this situation.  My thinking was that if this case hasn't come up before, perhaps my programming logic is simply incorrect.

Comment: Good call, on the choice and the observation ;-)  I try not to "critique" when I can help it, and just focus on the question at hand, but my mind's first thought path was indeed restructuring the code layout :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer: use an @example tag.**

I also changed my setup, and it seems to be the best way to utilize what PHP has to offer without forfeiting usability:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $values Either an array of values to add, or multiple values
 * @example
 * 
 * $object->add('1');
 * $object->add('1','2');
 * $object->add(array('1','2'));
 * 
 * @return type 
 */
public function add($values=null) {
    if (is_array($values)) {
        return $this->addAll($values);
    } else {
        return $this->addAll(func_get_args());
    }
}
```